# FFmpeg libx264 Gamma Issue

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm aware that the gamma issue exists for both Quicktime's native H264 format as well as ffmpeg's equivalent libx264 format. My question is has anyone figured out a fix for it that's more programmatically automated than doing the manual Straight Alpha fix in Quicktime?

Either a command-line argument to perform the Straight Alpha and Save fix in QT or perhaps the magical command in ffmpeg's libx264 presets would work for me. Unfortunately, all I've read so far has seemed to indicate that I'm out of luck. Hopefully I'm wrong. Thanks!